# javascript RegEx to replace a number

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to take a number (eg. telephone number) of varying length and replace all but the last 4 characters with a '*' I know this should be easy but I can't get it to work.

Comment: `this should be easy but I can't get it to work` so what did you try? You probably don't even need a regex for this. A simple substring would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the regEx of `\d(?=\d{4})` did exactly what I was trying to achieve. I was being an idiot and not getting the lookahead to work properly.

or more fully:

```
var myNumber = 1234567890;
alert(myNumber.replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g,'*'));
```

did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var number = "3332221111";
var temp = "";
for(var i = 0; i < (number.length - 4); i++)
{
   temp += "*";
}
temp += number.substring((number.length - 4));
number = temp;
window.alert("" + number);
```

This way you don't need regex.  You can just add the number of * you need then add the last for digits.